# @media queries being ignored when css file is dynamic .php

Tags: css

I use PHP to merge and minify the css dynamically. It works well except @media queries are being ignored due to the file being .php

```
<link href="/minify_css.php" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet">
```

Anyway around this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with a static css file using the output of your `minify_css` ?

Comment: Did you set the `Content-Type` HTTP header ?

Comment: What is the content type of `minify_css.php`?

Comment: Yes in .php content type is css header('Content-type: text/css');

Comment: Can you supply us the sheet?